# How do I reliably style object layout in apache isis wicket viewer?

Tags: isis

I have created a module by copying module-simple. I have everything working well. However, the layout does not follow the layout.xml specification - I did not change anything except to rename the file.
This is the SimpleObject view.
[image: SimpleObject View]
This is my ZiemObject view - only the name is changed.
[image: This is my zoom object with exactly the same layout.xml]
 When I remove the layout.xml and try to use @MemberOrder(name=..,sequence = .. ) I get nothing but the basic object view.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me from your question, did you rename the layout file to ZiemObject.layout.xml ? I guess it must be because a layout is the only way to specify tabs. Could you paste a copy of it here?

Even better, perhaps you could upload your app to a github repo so we can take a deeper look?

### UPDATE:

I downloaded the sample app from the github repo, and what's there works as expected...

- the `ZiemObject.layout.xml` controls the member order of the `ZiemObject`, and because it is present the `@MemberOrder` annotation in that class are ignored
- Also, the `notes` property is no longer shown as multi-line because that metadata is only provided in the `.layout.xml` file
- if I rename the layout file, eg `mv ZiemObject.layout.xml ZiemObject.layout.xml.MOVED` then the default layout is honoured.  In particular, the (framework-defined) `id` and `version` fields are no longer shown in tabs.

(Also, the notes is no longer shown as multi-line because that metadata is only provided in the `.layout.xml` file).

- If I change the `@MemberOrder#sequence` attribute for the `name` and `notes` properties to "2" and "1" respectively, then the order of these fields is inverted, as shown below:

[image]

Hope that helps
Dan

Comment: here is the repo https://github.com/jamesagada/ziem. What s the purpose of the @MemberOrder annotation if you must use Layout.xml?

Comment: @MemberOrder is used if layout.xml is not present.  And the most common use case when layout.xml *is* present to associate actions with properties or collections ... saves having to also add those actions in the layout.xml.

I'll take a look at your example repo, thanks.

Comment: I've updated by answer referencing your example app.